# Need help w/ java code

Tags: java, methods

Problem "Write a method  isMultiple that determines, for a pair of integers , whether  the second integer  is a multiple of the first. The method  should take two integer  arguments  and return true  if the second is a multiple of the first and false  otherwise. [Hint: Use the remainder operator .] Incorporate this method  into an application that inputs a series of pairs of integers  (one pair at a time) and determines whether  the second value  in each pair is a multiple of the first.har()"

Keep getting "The value of your output is incorrect." Have tried doing multiple things to fix but not sure what's wrong. When I click for feedback I get

Expected Output:

```
·Enter·one·number:Enter·a·second·number:9·is·a·multiple·of·3↵    
Do·you·want·to·enter·another·pair(y/n)?Enter·one·number:Enter·a·second·number:99·is·a·multiple·of·11↵
Do·you·want·to·enter·another·pair(y/n)?Enter·one·number:Enter·a·second·number:7·is·a·multiple·of·7↵
Do·you·want·to·enter·another·pair(y/n)?Enter·one·number:Enter·a·second·number:3·is·not·a·multiple·of·9↵
Do·you·want·to·enter·another·pair(y/n)?↵
```

Actual Output:

```
·Enter·one·number:Enter·a·second·number:9·is·a·multiple·of·3↵
Do·you·want·to·enter·another·pair(y/n)?↵
Enter·one·number:
```

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated ^_^

Code I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Multiples {

public static void main(String [] args){

    boolean run = true;

    while(run = true){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter one number:");
    int num1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a second number:");
    int num2 = input.nextInt();

    boolean result = isMultiple(num1,num2);


    if(result = true){
        System.out.println(num2 + " is a multiple of " + num1);
    }

    else{
        System.out.println(num2 + " is not a multiple of " + num1);
    }

    System.out.println("Do you want to enter another pair(y/n)?");
    String a = input.next();

    if(YesOrNo(a)){
       break;
    }


    }


}

    public static boolean YesOrNo(String a){

        if(a.equals("y"))
            return false;
        else if(a.equals("n"))
            return true;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static boolean isMultiple (int x , int y){

         if(x % y == 0 || y % x == 0)
             return true;   
         else
             return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Format of expected input is unreadable, please use same formatting as source

Comment: From the input/output you posted, your code appears to be working. What is the case where you are getting the error, and what is giving the error?

Comment: The problem is on the site MyProgrammingLab, and I think it's just being picky about the code. Not sure, the last time I had an issue with this site it was just spacing, so prob. something minor.

Answer (score 1):

When you are checking you have to do it like this:

```
if(result == true){
```

Comment: changed it but no result, still getting the same error for actual output and expected output.

Comment: When I run your code it works - with the right checking (==) in while and if,

Comment: yea I'm not sure, when I run it in excel it works fine. But trying to submit it on MyProgrammingLab is giving me issues.